# Adding a close button to an accordion effect

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have a jQuery issue that I cant get my head around.  Basically, I have a horizontal timeline that shows a number of events of a company.  These events are set up with an accordion effect which is working fine.  I am trying to add a close button to each accordion panel and am getting stuck in a loop at the moment.

If the panel is clicked on, the code checks to see whether or not there is a class attached called "active".  If not, it adds it and expands the panel.  I have added my close link and said to remove the "active" class, which works, but once it realises it no longer has the class, it re-adds it.  So I am stuck in this loop which I cant get out of :)

Any help would be great!

A jsfiddle of the issue can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/damienoneill2001/DdALd/8/

As you click through the different panels, you can see they work.  A Close button is set on the second panel and becomes visible once any panel is clicked.  If you click on the close button but then click on the same panel again, you can see it gets caught in the loop.

Also, if you open a panel, click on the same panel again to close and then try open it again, it gets caught in the same loop.

**jQuery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {
    activePanel = $("#accordion .panel:first");
    $(activePanel).addClass('active');
    $(".panel").click(function(){

if($(this).not('.active') )
{
    $(this).animate({width: "400px"}, 300);
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(activePanel).animate({width: "60px"}, 300);
    activePanel = this;
    $('.close').css({display: "block"});

    }

}); 
$(".close").click(function(){
     $('.close').css({display: "none"});
     $('.panel').removeClass('active');
    });

});
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for that?

Comment: cool, will do that now!

Comment: If you provide a fiddle, it will be easy for us to give a solution to your problem

Comment: Just working on getting the styles in the fiddle.  Its just not looking the way it should just get.  I wont be much longer

Comment: @AnoopJoshi fiddle added now.  sorry about the delay.  I ended up putting the whole code in as the snippet I was trying didnt work out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `hasClass`

```
if(!$(this).hasClass('.active') )
{
    $(this).animate({width: "400px"}, 300);
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(activePanel).animate({width: "60px"}, 300);
    activePanel = this;
    $('.close').css({display: "block"});

}
```

**Edit**

I've updated your code provided in the fiddle

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    activePanel = $("#accordion div.panel:first");
    $(activePanel).addClass('active');
    $(".panel").click(function () {
        if ($(this).not('.active')) {
            $(".active").animate({
                width: "60px"
            }, 300);
            if ($(this).css("width") == "400px") {
                $(this).animate({
                    width: "60px"
                }, 300);
                $('.close').hide();
            } else {
                $(this).animate({
                    width: "400px"
                }, 300);
                $('.close').show();
            }
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }

    });
    $(".close").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).hide();
        $(".active").animate({
            width: "60px"
        }, 300);

    });

});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DdALd/19/)

Comment: Hi @Anoop!  This has not worked unfortunately.  The panels dont have the class .active until they have actually been clicked/opened.  When using `hasClass`, the panels do not open at all for me

Comment: @damienoneill2001 I forgot to put ! in the code. Can you check this code??

Comment: this is now allowing the panels to open, but I am still getting the same issues that I have starting out.  I am just still trying to tidy up the jsfiddle and will post it asap!

Comment: Hey @Anoop.  That is looking great however there is just one little thing, if I add in a second .close, the code doesnt seem to be able to handle it.  Each panel will require a close button each.  You can see what happens here: http://jsfiddle.net/damienoneill2001/DdALd/20/

Comment: see this updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/DdALd/21/ Dont forget to accept the answer. I spent so much time on this. :)

Comment: sorry @Anoop, one last thing.  If I open the slide with the close button and then open a different slide without closing the first slide, the close button remains.  Is it possible to remove this one too?

Comment: yes. use  $(".close").hide(); in close button click

Answer (score 0):

change `not` to `is`

```
if(!$(this).is('.active') )
{
    $(this).animate({width: "400px"}, 300);
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(activePanel).animate({width: "60px"}, 300);
    activePanel = this;
    $('.close').css({display: "block"});

    }
```

Comment: Hey @subin, thanks for your answer however it is still doing the same thing.  Just sitting in a loop.  It displays none on .close and removes .active but immediately re-adds displays .close and .active again on that panel